# Is there an implemented function in Bukkit / Spigot MC (Java) that lets me get a players ping to the server?

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft, bukkit

I'm currently trying to code a Minecraft plugin for a server that a Streamer friend of mine wants to run. What I need is the following:

I need a function or method that lets me get the players ping towards the server. So that the player types `/ping` into the chatbox and gets a response from the server that looks something like `[Server]: Your current Ping is 62ms.`

I've looked in Bukkit documentation like http://docs.codelanx.com/Bukkit/1.7.10/ or http://bukkit.luricos.de/api/1.7.9-R0.2/, but I couldn't find something that fits my needs.

My Plugin.yml:

```
name: Beginning
version: ${project.version}
main: de.nightcore.beginning.Main
api-version: 1.16

commands:
  date:
    description: Shows the current time and Date
  ping:
    description: Gives the Player its current ping to the server
```

My Main Class:

```
package de.nightcore.beginning;

import de.nightcore.beginning.commands.DateCommand;
import de.nightcore.beginning.commands.PingCommand;
import de.nightcore.beginning.listeners.JoinListener;
import de.nightcore.beginning.listeners.QuitListener;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable()
    {
        Bukkit.getLogger().fine("Plugin wird geladen!");

        listenerRegistration();
        commandRegistration();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable()
    {
        Bukkit.getLogger().fine("Plugin wird beendet!");
    }

    public static String getPrefix()
    {
        return ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Server" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "] " + ChatColor.WHITE;
    }

    private void listenerRegistration()
    {
        PluginManager pluginManager = Bukkit.getPluginManager();
        pluginManager.registerEvents(new JoinListener(), this);
        pluginManager.registerEvents(new QuitListener(), this);
    }

    private void commandRegistration()
    {
        getCommand("date").setExecutor(new DateCommand());
        getCommand("ping").setExecutor(new PingCommand());
    }
}
```

And finally my PingCommand Class:

```
package de.nightcore.beginning.commands;

import org.bukkit.Server;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.*;

//TODO: Ping Command / Command that provides Connection Info

public class PingCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        Player player = sender.getServer().getPlayer("%UUID%"); ;
        Server server = sender.getServer();

        //Source Code to provide information about the players current ping

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @tibetiroka Im still having the issue that my IntelliJ shows me, that in `int ping = ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().ping;` the `CraftPlayer` cant be resolved. Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You might need access to packets via ProtocolLib

Comment: @tibetiroka after some research i came across 2 problems. First the most current Version of ProtocolLib doesnt support MC 1.16.4 and Second, even if it would, all the tutorials on how to implement it into my code are so confusing and i dont really get how to do it. Since im not that big of a "Java Pro"

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast Player to CraftPlayer, after that get the EntityPlayer with CraftPlayer#getHandler(), where you can return the player ping as int value.

```
((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().ping;
```

You also need to add the spigot dependency (the API doesn't seem to include it).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: so I tried to add this to the pom.xml file but it doesnt change anything. I changed the ```<version>LATEST</version>``` to ```<version>1.16.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>``` but it seems like it doesnt work correctly. I copied my entire pom.xml for you maybe i did something wrong. [PasteBin Link](https://pastebin.com/ufuV2E7f) Im not getting an Execption regarding a wrong dependency or something inside IntelliJ but it still shows me `Cannot resolve Symbol CraftPlayer` .